# XSD unique constraint with field to multiple member

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a structure like this:

```html
<EnumDefinitions>
    <EnumDefinition enumName="MyEnum1">
        <Values>
            <Value value="1" valueName="MyEnumValue1"/>
            <Value value="2" valueName="MyEnumValue2"/>
        </Values>
    </EnumDefinition>
    <EnumDefinition enumName="MyEnum10">
        <Values>
            <Value value="10" valueName="MyEnumValue10"/>
            <Value value="20" valueName="MyEnumValue20"/>
        </Values>
    </EnumDefinition>
</EnumDefinitions>
<EnumReference EnumName="MyEnum1" EnumValueName="MyEnumValue0"/>
<EnumReference EnumName="MyEnum1" EnumValueName="MyEnumValue10"/>
```

I want that the first EnumReference is valid but the second one should fail.
For that I tried this unique and keyref:

```html
    <xs:keyref name="keyref_EnumNameValue" refer="unique_EnumNameValuePair">
        <xs:selector xpath="EnumReference"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@EnumName"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@EnumValueName"/>
    </xs:keyref>
    <xs:unique name="unique_EnumNameValuePair">
        <xs:selector xpath="EnumDefinitions/EnumDefinition"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@enumName"/>
        <xs:field xpath="Values/Value/@valueName"/>
    </xs:unique>
```

but then I receive an error by validating:
Field '{anonymous}' of identity constraint 'unique_EnumNameValuePair' evaluates to a node-set with more than one member.

Is there a possibility to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XSD's key/unique and keyref: You can separately ensure that an @EnumName value's attribute matches an existing @enumName, and that an @EnumValueName is matched by a @valueName; given the current EnumDefinition structure (which makes sense from an object orientation), you cannot achieve BOTH at the same time.

I can see why - e.g. usability for the programmer using your XML - you may choose to duplicate (denormalize in database terms) values by copying them in EnumReference's @EnumName and @EnumValueName. You may want to consider though that this has a negative effect in terms of performance and size of XML; particularly if there are a lot of EnumReference in your XML...

An alternative, very much in line with a relational model, may be to simply add an identifying attribute for each of the EnumDefinition's Value elements, say @aid. Your XML would then look like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<root>
    <EnumDefinitions>
        <EnumDefinition enumName="MyEnum1">
            <Values>
                <Value aid="a" value="1" valueName="MyEnumValue1"/>
                <Value aid="b" value="2" valueName="MyEnumValue2"/>
            </Values>
        </EnumDefinition>
        <EnumDefinition enumName="MyEnum10">
            <Values>
                <Value aid="c" value="10" valueName="MyEnumValue10"/>
                <Value aid="d" value="20" valueName="MyEnumValue20"/>
            </Values>
        </EnumDefinition>
    </EnumDefinitions>
    <EnumReference aid="a"/>
    <EnumReference aid="f"/>
</root>
```

The XSD, with constraints, could then be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="EnumDefinitions">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="EnumDefinition">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="Values">
                                            <xsd:complexType>
                                                <xsd:sequence>
                                                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Value">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:attributeGroup ref="aid"/>
                                                            <xsd:attribute name="value" type="xsd:unsignedByte" use="required"/>
                                                            <xsd:attribute name="valueName" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                </xsd:sequence>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                            <xsd:key name="ValueUC">
                                                <xsd:selector xpath="Value"/>
                                                <xsd:field xpath="@value"/>
                                            </xsd:key>                                          
                                            <xsd:key name="ValueNameUC">
                                                <xsd:selector xpath="Value"/>
                                                <xsd:field xpath="@valueName"/>
                                            </xsd:key>                                          
                                        </xsd:element>
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                    <xsd:attribute name="enumName" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:key name="EnumNameUC">
                        <xsd:selector xpath="EnumDefinition"/>
                        <xsd:field xpath="@enumName"/>
                    </xsd:key>                  
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="EnumReference">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="aid"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:key name="PK">
            <xsd:selector xpath="EnumDefinitions/EnumDefinition/Values/Value"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="@aid"/>
        </xsd:key>
        <xsd:keyref name="FK" refer="PK">
            <xsd:selector xpath="EnumReference"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="@aid"/>
        </xsd:keyref>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:attributeGroup name="aid">
        <xsd:attribute name="aid" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    </xsd:attributeGroup>
</xsd:schema>
```

It looks like so:

[image]

It means:

- your cross reference is there in terms of PK/FK constraints
- your integrity is assured by UC suffixed constraints.

If you cannot do anything about structure, then the only alternatives left are Schematron on top of XSD 1.0, or move to an XSD 1.1 processor (not that spread at this time, and good luck finding good,  free processors across platforms).